# How to ignore other instances of a word when looping it via pandas.groupby.agg?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, nltk, pandas-groupby

I have a code (see below) that I used to match word occurrences per Location. My problem is that it reads all instances of the word.

FOR EXAMPLE: This is what I was hoping it to do, but the code below counted all occurrences of 'help' including 'helping' and 'helped'

```
      tidytext2                  |  Location    |    occurrences    
she used to help me              |     Aus      |        1
help is on the way               |     UK       |        1  
Helping is a kind gift           |     UK       |        0
She helped me when I needed it   |     Japan    |        0
Why dont u help me?              |     SA       |        1
Help me! Im hungry help          |     Rwanda   |        2


words = [i[0] for i in pos_freq.most_common()]

for i in words:
    positivedf[i] = positivedf.tidytext2.str.count(i)

funs = {i: 'sum' for i in words}
groupedpos = positivedf.groupby('Location').agg(funs)
```

I got positive_freq.most_common() using the following codes. It returns

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
def process_text(text):
    tokens = []
    for line in text:
        toks = tokenizer.tokenize(line)
        toks = [t.lower() for t in toks if t.lower() not in stopwords_list]
        tokens.extend(toks)

    return tokens

tokenizer=TweetTokenizer()
punct = list(string.punctuation)
stopwords_list = stopwords.words('english') + punct 
pos_lines = list(positivedf.tidytext2)
pos_tokens = process_text(pos_lines)
pos_freq = nltk.FreqDist(pos_tokens)
pos_freq.most_common()
[('help', 7)]
```

Comment: what are tidytext2 and positivedf?

Comment: @ehsan its a dataframe and its column 'tidytext2

Comment: so the text column on the dataframe above is different that tidytext2?

Comment: @ehsan the columns above are examples to visualise the problem with regards to the word help.

Comment: I changed the name of the column from text to tidytext2. Its the same format

Comment: Sorry but which part does this go? The second one batch of code?

Comment: my bad I think, so you want to above mentioned results right?

Comment: Basically I want the code to be able to differentiate between 'help' and 'helped'/'helping'. Right now, it s counting all occurrences of help as one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use regex for this:

```
for i in words:
    positivedf[i] = positivedf.tidytext2.str.count(r'(?<!\S)'+i+'(?!\S)')
```

If you want to be case insensitive:

```
for i in words:
        positivedf[i] = positivedf.tidytext2.str.count(r'(?i)(?<!\S)'+i+'(?!\S)')
```

Comment: SMART! Thank you Ehsan!

Comment: glad it helped. Best,